# Formatting issues duplicating table

Tags: vba, ms-word

## Forward

I am making a "label program" that will print waybill information. Consists of a table in Word on a custom 3x5 inch document with 0 margins.

[image: My Label]

I currently have a simple form that, if you need copies, it will edit one of the cells so that each time it prints the "pieces count" is incremented. 1of10, 2of10, 3of10.....

While that worked the code submitted a separate print job for each "label". That created a problem for the end user where they would have to wait about 5-10 seconds between print jobs. When printing a couple of hundred of these at a time those seconds can add up.

## Corrective solution

To try an alleviate this problem I wanted to make copies of the table so that 100 labels would be printed as one 100 page document. Found several solutions for copying pages of text but I have tables which complicated things. The closest solution I have found was:

```
With ActiveDocument
    .Tables(1).Range.Copy
    .Range.Select
    '.Range.InsertAfter (Chr(11))
    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Selection.Paste
End With
```

And this does make a perfect copy of the table however it is merging the tables together. So if I wanted to loop this to create several more labels it would be doubling up the results every time since the code above just copies the first tabel.

To try and fix that issue I added a line break (vertical tab) before the paste. You will see that as the commented out line in the above snippet. This breaks up the tables but adds too much whitespace in between.

Page breaks seems like the solution here. While those did make the table break up they ended up creating a blank page in between each label which I was having enough of a time clearing from the GUI let alone in VBA.

[image: Multiple labels with line breaks]

## The actual question

How can I take a table that is perfectly designed to fit on one 3x5 inch page and duplicate it X times. The caveat is I need to be able to find the cell programically that contains the pieces text. Currently I can use these absolute reference for the first table

```
 ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(5, 1).Range.Text
```

So if I had 3 tables for instance I need to be able to call each table and edit the text of the `Cell(5, 1)`.

**In case you ask**

I know this functionality is better placed inside actual label programs like Bartender but those cost money that the company will not allocate for the only label my company uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right concept was there. We needed to add a break in between the tables to disassociate them. Adding the vertical tab `Chr(11)` was obviously not the correct way to do it.

A proper section break would be the route to go here. Looking at MSDN you can see there are [multiple types of section breaks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195905.aspx). After testing a desirable outcome was acheived from using `wdSectionBreakNextPage` which is a "Section break on next page."

Basically just needed to add one line to the above code.

```
With ActiveDocument
    .Tables(1).Range.Copy
    .Range.Select
End With

With Selection
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .InsertBreak (wdSectionBreakNextPage)
    .Paste
End With
```

I hate the use of `Selection` and I am going to look into that but for now this does function properly.

Since the tables are not single units we are able to query `.Tables` in order to edit each page individually.